# Horizontal Scrolling using JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to know if there is any open-source free script available for a horizontal scrolling website. I used [this](http://flesler.blogspot.in/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) script but it has an issues running in IE.

Could someone suggest any script similar to [this](http://www.techfest.org/) website?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of such widgets provided by a bunch of different javascript libraries.

- [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/)
- [Prototype/Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/)
- JSMadeEasy as posted by FacilityDerek above.

and Have a look at these [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) scripts:

- The first is a scrolling menu: [Horizontal Scrolling Menu made with CSS and jQuery](http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/) Example [here](http://valums.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/menu/final.htm)
- The second is a scrolling pane [jScrollHorizontalPane](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jscrollhorizontalpane) example [here](http://threeformed.com/labs/jScrollHorizontalPane/examples/basicScroller.html)
- Here is a more simple one also using jQuery: [simplyScroll v1](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html)
- If what you want is more of a news ticker, you might find this interesting: [liScroll (a jQuery News Ticker made easy) 1.0](http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/scrollanimate.html)

Answer (score 2):

[jScrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/) will do the trick. It's cross browser.